# Derivative of output gate in LSTM

Tags: partial-derivative, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm going through "Sequence Models" course by deeplearning.ai on coursera. But I've get confused on first hometask. While forward pass in lstm, we have:
[image: **enter image description here**]

But then it continues, saying that in backpropagation we have the following derivative for output gate:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Prefix $d$ means the "derivative of loss function $L$ with respect to". $t$ - at t-th time(iteration). Suppose we have some loss function $L$ let's do a math:
$$
d\Gamma_o^{<t>}=\frac{\delta L}{\delta \Gamma_{o}^{<t>}} = \frac{\delta L}{\delta a^{<t>}} \frac{\delta a^{<t>}}{\delta \Gamma_{o}^{<t>}}= da^{<t>}tanh(c^{<t>})
$$
As you see, there is no $\Gamma_o^{<t>}(1-\Gamma_o^{<t>})$. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
But you know, this expression looks like a derivative of sigmoid function used in equation $(5)$. Because:
$$
\frac{\delta \sigma(x)}{\delta x} = \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))
$$
So, maybe it is a derivative of $L$ with respect to another variable(let's say to $W_a$), but not to $\Gamma_o^{<t>}$. In that case we have:
$$
\frac{\delta L}{\delta \Gamma_{o}^{<t>}}=\frac{\delta L}{\delta a^{<t>}}\frac{\delta a^{<t>}}{\delta \Gamma_o^{<t>}}\frac{\delta \Gamma_o^{<t>}}{\delta W_a}
$$
And in the right side of this equation the last multiplier is equal to $\Gamma_o^{<t>}(1-\Gamma_o^{<t>})$. But this is not the case, because they write $d\Gamma_o^{<t>}$ Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the (*) operation is a Hadamard Product.

In Hadamard operation, say we have F = A (*) B

d(F)/d(A) would be d(A) (*) B

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).